# View contents of Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to be able to see the contents of the `Core Data` contained in my iPhone simulator app from the command line.

I've tried "cd'ing" into `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications` and then using `find . -name MyAppName` to find which of these directories contains my app:

```
29EB3FF9-4691-474D-8B05-AB168899D528 4C25697B-04D9-4B48-BE5E-D1E9B2E03381 A1DF7916-AE39-4367-BFD2-22A8BAA2AFD2 BDB577A8-0BCF-4E58-896B-D4E704F261D0 CC3CC638-E39D-4AE7-8580-4E8BBD375DC4 D11D7C57-5578-4531-85BB-71AE6DD68B2F
```

Then I navigate to the "Documents" folder inside this folder, but the only "sqlite" files I see are  `CoreDataTabBarTutorial.sqlite     CoreDataTabBarTutorial.sqlite-shm CoreDataTabBarTutorial.sqlite-wal`.  (**EDIT**: I had actually named my `persistentStoreCoordinator`'s `URL` to `CoreDataTabBarTutorial.sqlite`).

I'm sure that my objects get inserted to "Core Data", but it appears they don't persist between launches of Interface Builder. I'm trying to debug that.

Comment: So what you *actually* mean is that you want to view the contents of SQLLite-back CoreData store?   I am also very confused about *'but it appears they don't persist between launches of Interface Builder'* is this really what you mean?

Comment: When you create your persistent store, check what type and name you're using to initialize it.

Comment: Thanks, I was setting the `persistentStoreCoordinator`'s `URL` to `CoreDataTabBarTutorial.sqlite`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Core Data is saved on the device with sqlite.

You can use `sqlite3 CoreDataTabBarTutorial.sqlite` to view you database from the command line.  You will need to use the various sqlite3 commands and SQL to see any values.  [See Docs](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html)

```
.table will list the tables
select * from ZYOURTABLENAME; (do not forget semi-colon) will display the rows.
```

There is a [Mac app called Base](http://menial.co.uk/base/) that is a GUI tool for viewing sqlite databases.

Answer (score 7):

In order to Know the path of your sqlite file , follow the these steps

1) Open AppDelegate of your project.

2) There must exists a var with declaration as (only if you have checked Use CoreData while creating your project):

> lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {

3) Find this a line similar to

> let url =
>   self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")

4) print this url as

> print("persistentStoreCoordinator url : (url)")

5) Run your app find this url in console
6) copy that url , open terminal , type cd then paste this url 
url be like

> (file:///Users/prnjls/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A2B99983-4B71-4708-A515-7A87463ECF0C/data/Containers/Data/Application/F70EF393-FBF7-4598-B28B-9DAACBFE46F8/Documents/SingleViewCoreData.sqlite)

7) Download and install a free app to view sqlite data [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/liya/id455484422?mt=12)

8) Open On Liya Click on File -> New -> select sqlite in Database type -> click on the icon near it -> navigate to that sqlite file using  the path you copied.

9) You Can find all your entities you have saved tap on any Entity name and click on **Run SQL Command**  .
 That's it .
Hope it will help someone anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I know is with with [CoreDataUtility](https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility).

Just follow these steps:

1. Download latest binary https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility/wiki
2. Unzip and run app
3. Select Menu->File->New Project
4. Select "iOS Simulator" tab
5. Select "Simulator App" button
6. Select your app in the drop down list and select OK
7. Select "File" button and navigate up two directories
8. Select Documents and find your "persistence" file (it will be named CoreDataTabBarTutorial.sqlite or whatever you initialize in your code)
9. Make sure "SQL" is selected
10. Click "Open"
11. Click File->Save Project so you can just double click on the project file next time.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Apple Automator bash script and copy this below, and download DB Browser for SQLite to open core data

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
cd `ls -t -d */ | head -n 1`data/Containers/Data/Application 
cd `ls -t | head -n 1`"/Library/Application Support/<APPNAME>"
open -a DB\ Browser\ for\ SQLite ./<AppName>.sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a super old question but I recent wrote a small simple library that lets you view the contents of your Core Data Store while debugging your app. It gives you a custom popup viewer inside the app your are working on rather than having to download a SQL viewer [Check it out here](https://github.com/richmondwatkins/RWCoreDataViewer)

Add to your Podfile

```
pod 'RWCoreDataViewer', :git => 'https://github.com/richmondwatkins/RWCoreDataViewer'
```

Make your managed object's a member of the RWCoreDataInspector protocol. (There is nothing to implement here just include it in your class declaration)

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import RWCoreDataViewer

class MyEntity: NSManagedObject, RWCoreDataInspector {

}
```

To display your data just paste in:

```
RWCoreDataViewer.initialize(self.managedObjectContext)
```

And thats it. Whenever you want to display your data just add the initializer and you will get a custom view with all of your entities and their records

Answer (score -5):

Try to show hide files:
`defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles 1 && killall Finder`
And find files again.